# use tab-indent when tab button is pressed in textarea but it is going to next element in html

Tags: html, css

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

This is the code i just need an output in which whenever tab is placed it indent to right.. but pressing tab do something else

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following example: http://www.jqversion.com/#!/liDxmDg

you can use a jQuery code to accomplish that:

```
$(document).delegate('textarea', 'keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var start = $(this).get(0).selectionStart;
    var end = $(this).get(0).selectionEnd;

    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, start)
                + "\t"
                + $(this).val().substring(end));

    // put caret at right position again
    $(this).get(0).selectionStart =
    $(this).get(0).selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
});
```